# What would work better in order to get feedback upon unsubscribing from newsletter?

Tags: email, newsletter, user-feedback

In our email newsletters the user will find an unsubscribe link...

- Should that link when clicked automatically unsubscribe the user? Or should they be presented with a form to confirm the action?
- I would also like to get some kind of feedback as to why they are removing from our list, should we have an input box or select options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that clicking unsubscribe should immediately unsubscribe the user and they should be given the option to undo the action if it was a mistake.

Also, if you want to get some feedback, present it before the unsubscribe button and the remaining sequence should be the same.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIbQcU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I think placing an HTML form into email (option B) is not the best idea due to some reasons (technical and psychological). It is more convient to have it on the web page. Or you meant unsubscribe link in email leads to unsubscribe web page which contains Unsubscribe button?

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko I understand the technical issues, What are the psychological reasons that you mentioned?

Comment: Psychological reasons are a) a command button has more strong call to action effect compared to link. So the Unsubscribe button looks like strong invitation to action. As there no other options (like Do not unsubscribe) – you mentally  propose no alternative to user, i.e. push him. So, in short, it looks like call to action; b) listing reasons to unsubscribe can bias user decision, i.e. he reads reason, thinks and agrees although initially he has no strong decision to unsubscribe. So, in short, list of reasons frames the user(framing effect); c) form in email makes it more complex to perceive.

Comment: Sorry, there is text limitation )

Comment: +1 for instant unsubscribe. I can't tell you how annoying it is to try to unsubscribe from mobile and be taken to a form where I'm supposed to login or enter my e-mail address.